# I Need to cache data on my mvc project. what's proper way?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture, singleton

I've got an mvc project. we have some data that must collected for each user. i created some singleton class to cache data for better responsibility. 
somebodies avoided using singleton class in their projects.
i want to know do you prefer this and if not, what's your replacement??

Comment: Read here: [HttpCache vs Singleton - Best practice for an MVC application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990623/httpcache-vs-singleton-best-practice-for-an-mvc-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way in 99% is not reinventing the wheel. If you're not all right with `System.Web.Caching.Cache`, you can use `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache` instance per user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why you should not cache data in your singleton. I'm also using this way of caching in order to greatly reduce the amount of database calls. Just make sure that you keep your cache up to date.

I don't know your project and its environment, but in my case it there were situations when the data in the DB gets changed from another application. I implemented a database trigger to resolve this issue. You should consider doing the same in your case, so whenever some of your locally cached data changes in the DB, you get notified and can update the cache.

I think I don't have to mention this, but caching of course usually only makes sense for relatively *static* data that does not change very often.