# Should a static class be used for caching data in a ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a set of the data that hardly ever changes, but which is required frequently from many actions in my ASP.NET MVC application.
It seems too costly to do a database roundtrip every time that data is required, so I decided to cache it in a static class that looks like this:

```
public static class MyCache
{
    static DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper();
    static List<MyItem> myList = null;

    public static List<MyItem> Get {
        get
        {
            if (myList == null)
                myList = databaseHelper.GetAll();

            return myList;
        }
    }
}
```

Are there any issues in storing data like that? Are there better approaches to cache data?

Comment: "it seems costly" - it seems? That's it? Did you actually measure it? Are you sure you're not overly optimizing? Caching is difficult to get right, it often introduces bugs. So before you take on that effort, you should actually measure to see how costly it is. It may turn out there's more significant slowdowns elsewhere that you should focus on.

Comment: The properties is read only so I do not see issues.  Static is only issues when it is being changed by multiple methods. I would add locking when it is changed.

Comment: Just for clarification, Asp.Net MVC or Asp.Net Core MVC?

Comment: @BenSampica ASP.Net MVC, an old one.

Comment: @mason will take that into consideration

Comment: Related: [HttpCache vs. Singleton: Best practice for MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13990623/httpcache-vs-singleton-best-practice-for-an-mvc-application)

Answer (score 0):

When you say Cache then there are many things to consider.

1. How long data will stay in cache even after it is not consumed since long ?
2. What is the size of data ?
3. How you expire that data ? Are you sure that data you store in cache is not going to change once you load it ?

Now Static class as Cache ( More specially static fields). This is workable solution but you have to consider above points as well.

In your cache you have to consider that once you load in static field it is not going to load again till you restart application or set list as a null. Another advice is that list property only expose get as public and private for set so you have better control over it.